# Using the Standard Error of Prediction in the presence of practice effects

Tags: forecasting, prediction, standard-error, reliability

I’m wondering about the following hypothetical scenario.

There’s a student who previously scored 40% on an examination with a pass mark of 50%, a mean mark of 60%, SD of 10 and a reliability of 0.6. The student is now going to do the exam again.

I’ve been asked to build a confidence interval to indicate plausible outcomes when the student does the exam again, and from reading McManus (2012) I conclude that the best way to do this is by using the Standard Error of Prediction, which is defined as follows:

$\text{SE}_{\text{pred}} = \text{SD} \sqrt{(1 - \text{reliability}^2)}$
$\text{SE}_{\text{pred}} 
= 10 \sqrt{(1 - 0.6^2)} = 8$

I then calculate an estimated true score for this student, taking into account regression toward the mean.

$\text{Estimated True Score} = (0.6 \times 40) + 60 \times (1-0.6)) = 48$

Then taking the 95% confidence interval as

$48 \pm 1.96 \times \text{Standard Error of Prediction}$,

I get the confidence interval (32.32, 63.68). According to McManus (2012), I can use that to predict the student’s score on the second run of the exam.

However, there’s a problem which it seems is not addressed by McManus (2012). What if I know that on average students repeating the exam tend to gain 2 marks on average, due to practice effects?

It’s been suggested to me by a colleague that I should just add 2 marks the upper and lower bounds of the confidence interval and make the interval (34.32, 65.68) instead.

I sense this can be legitimate if I have reason to think that the practice effects are likely to be highly uniform across students. But what if I think they’ll instead be non-uniform, e.g. students who score 10 when first sitting the exam tend to gain a lot, while students who scored 40 will tend to gain less? What should I do then?

McManus, I. C. (2012). The misinterpretation of the standard error of measurement in medical education: A primer on the problems, pitfalls and peculiarities of the three different standard errors of measurement. *Medical Teacher*, 34, 569-576.

Comment: Sounds like it's time to start thinking about mixed models then with random student effect terms.